# Why do i keep getting syntax error if i have an "if" statement before?

Tags: php, syntax

Hi can somebody explain to me why do i get an unexpected else if i have an "if" statemant before?

PHP

```
<?php if($post_image=="") echo "There is no image" else echo '<img src="../img/'.$post_image.'">' ?>
```

Comment: For your own sanity, don't code like this.  You really should use `{}` with *all* `if`/`else` blocks.  Also, remember to use semicolons.

Comment: P.S. To "simplify", you can change this to: `<?php echo $post_image=="" ? "There is no image" : '<img src="../img/'.$post_image.'">' ?>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to terminate your statements with a semicolon:

```
<?php if($post_image=="") echo "There is no image"; else echo '<img src="../img/'.$post_image.'">'; ?>
```

Comment: You forgot one ;. ;)

Comment: If it's at the end of a php block it is not necessary.

Comment: Best practice would say to put it there anyway, especially since this question is about having missing semi colons :)

Comment: Edited to appease the masses

Comment: `Note: The closing tag of a PHP block at the end of a file is optional, and in some cases omitting it is helpful when using include or require, so unwanted whitespace will not occur at the end of files, and you will still be able to add headers to the response later. It is also handy if you use output buffering, and would not like to see added unwanted whitespace at the end of the parts generated by the included files. ` Just because it isn't needed, doesn't mean it's better to not have one. [Link Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)

Comment: the masses would also like line breaks please

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Who says it's at the end of a file?  I always omit at the end of a file.

Comment: Yea you are right thanks for the info ,i tought that if "else" is called i dont need the semicolons anymore :D

Comment: @danronmoon "the end of a file" implies at the end of a php block, since usually you're not closing and reopening a php block multiple (Srsly, no sane programmer does that).

Comment: It's an SO answer, not a file

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the semi colons. You have:

```
<?php if($post_image=="") echo "There is no image" else echo '<img src="../img/'.$post_image.'">' ?>
                                                  ^---- here                         and here ---^
```

And your need:

```
<?php if($post_image=="") echo "There is no image"; else echo '<img src="../img/'.$post_image.'">'; ?>
```